# Getting past the Synology default web site when creating a web server

Tags: server

I have my Wordpress site hosted on my Synology at my local address of `192.168.1.3`. I can access my website at that address with /wordpress. If I just use `192.168.1.3` or whatever my current public IP is, I get this screen.

[image]

I can't seem to get WordPress to show up when accessing my public IP address. I only get the above screen. So I know the web server itself is getting to the Internet, but I can't figure out why it won't see my WordPress site.

What info can I provide to help troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Because DNS doesn't know about your site. Perhaps adding the site's entry to your local 'hosts' file will help your computer find the site.

Although that will only help with *your* computer. Everyone else won't know about it (which may be what you want).

If it is a public site associated with a domain, then you'll need to get your hosting place to associate that domain name with your hosting IP.  But if it is a private/testing site that only you (and your computer) needs to access, then adding an entry in the local 'hosts' file will be your first step.